# Show applications in terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, applications, mojave, iterm

I am a developer and I want to access the applications folder through terminal. After typing in `cd Applications` and then `ls`. It doesn't show any of the contents inside the folder. I also tried `ls -a` to confirm wether they are stored as hidden files. But it didn't show them. I want to know a command or method to view the contents of the Application folder through terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main Applications directory is in the root directory, so you need to type

```
cd /Applications
ls -1
```

to access it (the `-1` option to `ls` will ensure that the applications are listed in a single column only).

Comment: There also can be an Applications directory in`~`, and this is what the OP changed directory into originally.

Comment: Or just `ls /Applications`